# How to match Strings in Rust

Tags: string, rust

I tried to match `String`s in Rust lang but I can't:

```
for (key, value) in obj.iter() {
    let valueType = match Some(value.to_string()) {
        Some(ref x) if x == "some_value" => string_gen(),
        _ => "test".to_string()
    };
    println!("{}", value);
    println!("{}", valueType);
}
```

I have to match the word "some_value" when the value of the iterator is "some_value"

I did a lot of searches and have a lot of people with the same problems.

Comment: Can you please create a [Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (MCVE) on the Rust playground? There are too many missing pieces here and you haven't shared any error messages or anything.

Comment: @SimonWhiteHead theres no error message, just don't match.What are missing in my doubt? theres the body, and the needs and the information, do you need more information?

Comment: I am assuming `obj` is a `HashMap`.. but it would be good to see how you've added values to it because the types of the key and value will depend on what was inferred based on how you initialized it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it by getting a `&str` out of the `String`, such as with this:

```
match Some(&*value.to_string()) {
    Some("some_value") => string_gen(),
    _ => "test".to_string()
}
```

But as far as pattern matching a `String` directly: no, you can’t. Pattern matching is all about structural comparisons rather than arbitrary user-defined code comparisons like `==` is able to do. `String` is a struct type with a handful of private fields, so you can’t match its insides. You can only get a `&str` out of it which can be compared.